# How is dill different from Python's pickle module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, dill

I have a large object in my Python3 code which, when tried to be pickled with the `pickle` module throws the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

However, `dill.dump()` and `dill.load()` are able to save and restore the object seamlessly.

1. What causes the trouble for the `pickle` module?
2. Now that `dill` saves and reconstructs the object without any error, is there any way to verify if the pickling and unpickling with `dill` went well?
3. How's it possible that `pickle` fails, but `dill` succeeds?

Comment: TL;DR: `pickle` doesn't handle functions or complex objects as well as `dill`. I use `dill` for all my Data Science pickling since the models and objects are very deep and complex

Comment: Dill is also built on top of pickle but like above, it's made for complex objects where pickle can't succeed.

Answer (score 66):

I'm the `dill` author.

1) Easiest thing to do is look at this file: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_objects.py, it lists what `pickle` can serialize, and what `dill` can serialize.

2) you can try `dill.copy` and `dill.check` and `dill.pickles` to check different levels of pickling and unpickling. `dill` also more includes utilities for detecting and diagnosing serialization issues in `dill.detect` and `dill.pointers`.

3) `dill` is built on `pickle`, and augments it by registering new serialization functions.

4) `dill` includes serialization variants which enable the user to choose from different object dependency serialization strategies (in `dill.settings`) -- including source code extraction and object reconstitution with `dill.source` (and extension of the stdlib `inspect` module).

Comment: Why is dill not merged into pickle?

Comment: @tejasvi88: Primarily, there's never been a PEP to do so.

Comment: dill is better, can't pickle while using multiprocessing

Comment: @Dee why can't pickle be used while multiprocessing?

Comment: I think Dee meant that multiprocessing uses pickle to pass objects across processes. A fork of multiprocessing (called multprocess) replaces pickle with dill.